# I am working with an app which,I have another team member

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an ios, app,it is in swift language.I have another team member.The app has many pages which we decided to program seprately.How can I integrate both of our pages in our app?Kindly help.

Comment: Here's a link that talks about the different team workflows using git, hopefully it gives you a starting point https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/

Comment: What part do you need help with? How to divide up the work? How to have multiple people make changes to the same project? How to avoid conflicts? As Roee says, the answer to most of those things is a version control system. Set up a server-based repository like Github and post upload your repo there. Then learn how to commit, push and pull, and learn about branching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use version control tools like Git

Comment: Can you explain bro please

Comment: read about version control (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). Basically, everyone of you will develop his own files, on his own mac, but it will be on one project that you will all share.

Comment: No problem. And if the answer helped you, please mark it as correct